# ¿Como modelar una relación N a M sin usar @ManyToMany?

Tags: spring, relaciones

estoy haciendo un proyecto de desarrollo web en Spring para una asignatura y en el diseño de las entidades me ha salido una relación N a M. En esta asignatura, los profesores me recomiendan usar una tabla intermedia y hacer dos relaciones 1 a N con la tabla intermedia, en vez de una relación N a M entre las dos entidades. Esto es porque permite añadir atributos propios de la relación, ahora y/o en el futuro de manera más fácil que con una relación N a M.

Mi problema viene a la hora de desarrollar. Y es que no se si la relación entre  las entidades y la tabla intermedia tiene que se unidireccional o bidireccional?

Si lo pongo unidireccional, en las entidades no tengo ningún atributo de la otra entidad. Entonces entiendo que tiene que ser bidireccional, pero tampoco estoy 100% seguro.

Os pongo un ejemplo para que se pueda ver mejor el caso:

Entidades Dirección y Empresa. Tienen una relación N a M, ya que puede ahaber mas de una empresa con la misma dirección y una empresa puede tener más de una dirección, ya que puede tener varios locales en diferentes calles.

Por lo tanto creo una tabla intermedia DireccionEmpresa que tiene los id de cada entidad. Cada entidad tiene una relación 1 a N con la tabla intermedia.

Si pongo la relación unidireccional, las entidades no tienen los atributos de cada una, si pongo bidireccional tendrá un atributo de DireccionEmpresa, pero esto no se si es correcto.

Un saludo y muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor seria bidirecional ya que si por algun motivo buscas empresas por dirección deberías ser capaz de dar todas las empresas que estan en esa dirección, y por el caso contrario si buscas las direcciones de la empresa esta también debería dártelas, asi que lo mejor es que puedas sacar datos de las 2 tablas; claro si el problema que tienes es como el ejemplo que das.